# Preserve order of SQL WHERE IN() clause with nested SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a list of item names ordered by count of items. Item names and corresponing id's are stored in `tabletwo` while `tableone` refers to items by id's:

```
      tableone              tabletwo
+--------+-----------+    +----+------+
| itemid | condition |    | id | name |
+--------+-----------+    +----+------+
| 2      | satisfied |    | 1  | foo  |
+--------+-----------+    +----+------+
| 1      | satisfied |    | 2  | bar  |
+--------+-----------+    +----+------+
| 3      | satisfied |    | 3  | hurr |
+--------+-----------+    +----+------+
| 3      | satisfied |    | 4  | durr |
+--------+-----------+    +----+------+
| 3      | satisfied |
+--------+-----------+
| 4      | satisfied |
+--------+-----------+
| 4      | satisfied |
+--------+-----------+
| 3      | nope      |
+--------+-----------+
| 1      | satisfied |
+--------+-----------+
```

SQL code:

```
SELECT `itemname` FROM `tabletwo` WHERE `id` IN (
    SELECT `itemid` FROM (
        SELECT count(`itemid`), `itemid`
        FROM `tableone`
        WHERE `some_codition`="satisfied"
        GROUP BY `itemid`
        ORDER BY count(`itemid`) DESC
    ) alias
)
```

The nested `SELECT` returns a list of item id's in descendant order: `3, 4, 1, 2`. This list is then used as an argument of an `IN()` clause. **The expected result of the whole query is: `hurr, durr, foo, bar` (in this exact order).** But the order is not preserved. I know it can be done like this: `ORDER BY FIELD(id, 3, 4, 1, 2)` but I don't know how to do this trick when the ordered list is fetched dynamically like in my case. Do I need to `SELECT` it again? Or temporary table maybe? Or is it better to build another query outside SQL?

Comment: Try using `JOIN` instead.

Comment: Specify the expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT t2.`itemname` 
FROM `tabletwo` AS t2
JOIN (    
   SELECT count(`itemid`) AS cnt, `itemid`
   FROM `tableone`
   WHERE `some_codition`="satisfied"
   GROUP BY `itemid`
) AS t1 ON t1.`itemid` = t2.`id`
ORDER BY t1.cnt DESC
```

You can create a derived table using the subquery of the `IN` operator and perform a `JOIN` to this table, so that you are able to use the `COUNT` in the `ORDER BY` clause of the main query.

Answer (score 3):

Use `JOIN` instead of `IN`:

```
SELECT
    t2.name
FROM tabletwo t2
LEFT JOIN tableone t1
    ON t1.itemid = t2.id
    AND t1.`condition` = 'satisfied'
GROUP BY
    t2.id, t2.name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

If you want to exclude rows from `tabletwo` that do not have a match on `tableone`, use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`.

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d2d0e/3/0)</kbd>